# Converting class to string

Tags: c++

This is derived from Herb Sutter's gotw3 (http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/003.htm).

With the following class and `FindAddr` function...

```
using std::string;
using std::list;

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee(const string& n, const string& a) : name(n), addr(a) { }
    string name;
    string addr;
};

string FindAddr(const list<Employee>& l, const string& name)
{
    string addr;
    list<Employee>::const_iterator i = find(l.begin(), l.end(), name);

    if (i != l.end()) {
        addr = (*i).addr;
    }
    return addr;
}
```

I get a compile error because the Employee class has no conversion to string.  I can see that such a conversion is not necessarily sensible, but for the purpose of the exercise, I added a naive conversion:

```
string::string(const Employee& e)
{
    return e.name;
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
gotw3.cc:17:9: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
string::string(const Employee& e)
~~~~~~  ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are trying to overload the casting, this link may help: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/

Comment: gotw3.cc - something about Sutter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two things: first, you cannot add to an existing class without
modifying the class definition.  If you have a class that you
want convertible to `std::string` (or to `double` or whatever),
you should define a conversion operator: in your case:

```
class Employee
{
    //  ...
    operator std::string() const
    {
        return name;  //  Or whatever...
    }
};
```

Second, the solution in your case isn't to provide an implicit
conversion, it is to use `std::find_if` with an appropriate 
matcher.  In C++11, this may be done by using a lambda, but in
general (and in older versions of C++), you can always define
a functional type.  For cases like this, where a class has an
natural "key", I would probably add a few member classes, along
the lines of:

```
class Match : std::unary_function<Employee, bool>
{
    std::string myName;
public:
    explicit Match( std::string const& name )
        : myName( name )
    {
    }
    bool operator()( Employee const& toBeMatched ) const
    {
        return toBeMatched.name == myName;
    }
};
```

Additional functional types defining an ordering relationship,
or equality of keys, might be in order as well.

Comment: Yes.  A typo on my part; I'll correct it.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the name of the predicate function from the Match class that I pass to `find_if`?

Comment: A functional object can be called like a function; that's what the overload of `operator()(...)` does.  You don't pass a function to `find_if`, you pass an instance of the class (e.g. `Match( whatImLookingFor )`).

Answer (score 3):

There is no class string, there is a class template std::basic_string.

You should never modify anything in the std namespace.

For the purpose of conversion of a type to string you can add

`Employee::operator std::string()`

or define a

`std::ostream& operator<<( const Employee& em, std::ostream& os );` - this way your type will work with `lexical_cast`.

.. but what you actually need here is `std::find_if()`.